# Grafana query when dashboard is not visible

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm wondering how Grafana fires it's queries (to the datasource).
Does it only fire queries when the dashboard/panel is visible or does it keep on firing queries based on the default time period of all dashboards ?

My assumption was that since Grafana itself doesn't store data, the queries would be on a need basis, but I've been seeing http requests occur periodically from my VM.

This is relevant for metrics such as CloudWatch etc, where each API call can be charged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Grafana dashboards/panels fire queries only when they are visible (loaded in the browser).

But you may have alert rules in the Grafana and they should be evaluated also periodically. So I guess alerts are source of your queries.